# How to find all open Firefox webpage titles

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a requirement to close all opened Firefox pages & tabs except a few pages.

Say in one Firefox instance I might opened Yahoo, Google, Microsoft, GMail, Facebook.
In another Firefox instance I might have opened Youtube, Adsense, StackOverflow etc...

Before I start execute my Selenium Test Suite, I want to close all Firefox pages except GMail & Youtube.

In QTP, we can achieve this by using `ChildObjects("Browser")`.

Can anybody tell me the Java code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

based on the title of the page you can perform your operation. After opening  all windows you should switch to all windows one by one using WindowHandlers and get their tiles. By checking with the titles you can close all those windows which ever you want.

```
 Set<String> windows=driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator itr=(Iterator) windows.iterator();
    while(itr.hasMoreElements())
    {
        driver.switchTo().window((String)itr.nextElement());
        System.out.println("Window title is"+driver.getTitle());
        if(!driver.getTitle().contains("gmail")||driver.getTitle().contains("youtube")))
            driver.close();
    }
```